# how to get all ts file code line count with using tslint?

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

### how to get all .ts file code line count with using tslint?

> Is it possible to get all .ts file code line count with using tslint? I can't get any details from any `tslint` documents. Kindly let me know if you have any other options.

Comment: where do you want to get them? command line? it seems to get that information [from the rule](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/master/src/rules/maxFileLineCountRule.ts#L51)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **[`vscode`](https://code.visualstudio.com/)**, you can instll this plugin **[`line-counter`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dollyn.line-counter)** from the market place.

which will have,

```
Count current file
Count workspace
```

probably you can use the 2nd option

Comment: Is it support for .ts file?

Comment: yes it does, torkspace total line count is: 
    total: 10285847
    comment: 1946417
    blank: 930088

Comment: just goto command pallete and click count workspace, it takes some time though

Answer (score 0):

For sublime text you can use the following:

Step 1: Turn on regex search after pressing Ctrl + Shift + F ( global search )

Step 2: Paste the following in find: ^(.*)$

Step 3: In your Where section use the folder in which you write all your ts code eg: src/**/*.ts

Press Find and the total number of lines will be given to you eg: 10220 matches across 150 files

Comment: Did you turn on the regex search, it's the first button in sublime search with symbol  .*